# How to set custom header only for main http url/sampler, not embedded resources?

Tags: jmeter

I have a website that requires a custom header to access.  How do I configure JMeter to only send this custom header to the main site URL/http request sampler, and not send it to any embedded resources such as appdynamics or googleapis?

Right now, I have several "HTTP Request" samplers trying to act like a browser by using HTTP Defaults and checking the "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" box.  The request URL is in the form of "https://example.com/path/."  This part needs the custom header to access.  When retrieving embedded resources (like fonts.googleapis.com), the custom header should not be sent. Any ideas on how I can get this configured?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be retrieving any embedded resources in your load test, you need to limit the scope of the embedded resources scanning to **your application under test domain only**

Any external domains like `googleapis` or  `appdynamics` must be excluded via **URLs must match** input (lives at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]

More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

Comment: I apologize - I gave a bad example. We actually did follow that post to exclude domains not under test. A better example: We have `some.cloud.dns.host.com` that should have a custom header but embedded resources (under test) such as `media.example.com` and `www.example.com` should not have custom headers sent.